# NEARBY URI and FACEBOOK NOTE ISSUE

Tags: google-nearby

I have this simple problem, we want to use the FACEBOOK NOTE landing page and link it with a NEARBY NOTIFICATION.

The strange thing is that even if the URI is OK for physical web on the NEARBY is not showing up the notification.

When we change it to another standard page it works.

Of course I used a SHORTNER link to do that.

LINK OF THE PAGE ON FACEBOOK:
https://www.facebook.com/notes/il-mago-del-fornello/zuppa-di-roveja-e-cumino/1734572063523531/

THIS LINK is confirmed to be compatible with PHYSICAL WEB on: https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/physical-web/url-validator/

But is not working.

Answer (score 0):

See if the message shows in the Nearby list view in Google Settings. If you find the message there, the message was configured correctly and may not being raised as a notification for other reasons (ex: poor feedback from users, or a backoff on the specific device). If the message does not show in the Nearby list view either, it may have been flagged as a policy violation. Check the text in the message and the destination page for appropriateness (ex: profane text won't be shown). A copy of the policies can be found here: https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/policies

If you turn on debug mode, you can find more information about why the message was not shown in the Nearby service portion of the bug report. 
https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/debug_mode